# Qt deploy cannot find Visual Studio installation directory

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having a problem with Qt Deployment:

After a windeployqt App.exe, it returns

```
Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicond.dll
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5SerialPort Qt5Widgets
All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5SerialPort Qt5Widgets
To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5SerialPort Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets
Warning: Cannot find Visual Studio installation directory, VCINSTALLDIR is not set.
```

(I have to use the Qt 5.12.2 (MSVC 2017 64-bit) console, in the windows powershell the command windeployqt isn't found).

It doesn't deploy the msvc dll. How can I set VCINSTALLDIR?

Someone can help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: can you call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat" before you are doing the windeployqt?

Comment: No, now I'm executing the bat file Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat

Comment: But  VCINSTALLDIR is not set yet

Comment: The one you are using sets the VSINSTALLDIR but the one that i mention sets the VCINSTALLDIR

Comment: I see  "VCINSTALLDIR is not set", but I don't know

Comment: "%VS140COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"  sets the VCINSTALLDIR

Comment: With VS2019 vsvars32.nbat returns succesful, while with VS2017 (i'm compiling this applicaiton with msvc2017) i didn't see anything.

Comment: on my computer %VS140COMNTOOLS% expands to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\ 
Can you look in that folder to see if there is a vsvars32.bat?

Comment: I can find that file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build, not in your path.

Answer (score 1):

For VS2019 Community
VCINSTALLDIR is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC.
Add to system variables and restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use VS's command prompt instead of Qt's one. Specifically I had to use `VS2017 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` instead of `Qt 5.12.12 (MSVC 2017 64-bit)`, although the precise versions will vary. Using VS's command prompt `windeployqt.exe` was able to find VC and deploy the correct `vcredist_x64.exe`.